# Magento 2 category in database, but not showing in admin or front end

Tags: database, magento2, categories

I have been adding categories for different types of aircraft, under a subcategory called "aircraft," which is a subcategory of the default root category. At one point, I created a category called "bombers" and saved it. It showed up in the treeview. Then, I created a category called "cargo" and it showed up under treeview, but "bombers" disappeared. When I tried to re-enter "bombers," I got the dreaded "URL key for specified store already exists." The category "bombers" does not show up in the admin treeview, and it does not show up on the front end either.

When I looked in the database, I saw there are entries for "bombers" in the catalog_category_entity_varchar table (see below). Do I/can I just delete these entries and try adding it again via the admin screen, or is it not that simple? I can just delete the category and start over, as I have no products associated with it yet. What should I do? Thank you.

["bombers" show up in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSIfd.jpg)

*** UPDATE ***
OK. I think I fixed this issue. First, I moved a copy locally (Windows/XAMPP), in case I screwed something up! I looked and saw two categories were both given entity_id of 60. I think that's what screwed everything up. I deleted any entries in any category tables that were 60. I then had to go into the marketing section of the admin area and delete the two url rewrites it created for 60. I could then add "Bombers" and "Fighters" and any other category I wanted to. Now, I just need to decide if I want to try and export the sql, or just make the changes manually on the server.

Let me know if what I did seems ok, and/of if there's more I need to do. Thanks.